# Does the word "got" in this context mean?

Tags: lyrics

From Taylor Swift's [Blank Space](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/taylorswift/blankspace.html):

> Nice to meet you
>
> Where you been?
>
> I could show you incredible things
>
> Magic, madness, heaven, sin
>
> Saw you there and I thought oh my god
>
> Look at that face, you look like my next mistake
>
> Love's a game, wanna play
>
> New money, suit and tie
>
> I can read you like a magazine
>
> Ain't it funny rumors fly
>
> And I know you heard about me
>
> So hey, let's be friends
>
> I'm dying to see how this one ends
>
> Grab your passport and my hand
>
> I could make the bad guys good for a weekend
>
> So it's gonna be forever
>
> Or it's gonna go down in flames
>
> You can tell me when it's over
>
> **If the high was worth the pain**
>
> **Got a long list of ex-lovers**
>
> They'll tell you I'm insane
>
> Cause you know I love the players
>
> And you love the game

Comment: It must be a contraction of "I have **got**"

Answer (score 1):

Got means have in this context. It's improper English but it is widely used in America.

In his case it's "I have a long list of ex-boyfriends"

Answer (score 1):

It means that the speaker **HAS** a long list of ex-lovers.

Based on the choices you provided, the speaker gained lovers and lost them; hence, the long list.

**Got** was used in an informal way.